# My phone has no zune

Tags: 8.0, zune

I just bought a Nokia Lumia 625 phone, and I realized there is no Zune app/software on it, so basically, I can't add music videos and pictures and can't even update the phone because It has no Zune. But there is an SD memory card which allows me to add pictures, musics, videos and etc. But my real question is, how do I install the Zune software on my phone? I need to install it because I'm using application deployment or SDK and Phone Emulator but it needs zune in order to make it work. please reply as soon as possible, I have a feeling that my Lumia 625 is not genuine Windows Phone 8.0

Comment: Are you talking about the Music+Videoes app? In Windows Phone 8, it is no longer called Zune. Let us know if you do not have this app.

Answer (score 5):

When you plug your phone in to your PC, you can copy media across using Windows Media Player; you no longer need to use the Zune application on the desktop. You can also just copy the files across using Windows Explorer as it will show up under "My Computer".

On the phone itself, the app is now called "Music+Videos" and is "X-Box green", with a headphones/X-Box logo as its live tile.:

[image]

With the 8.1 Update, the icon is No longer X-Box green, but instead your chosen accent colour. The icon is now just a pair of headphones, rather than being branded as X-Box music.

Comment: Wasn't Xbox Video split off into its own app, available in the store? That's what I use most days now, and I have no idea how I would access videos in my current Music app.

Comment: @Katana314 Definitely not the case on my phone, which uses the stock `Music+Videos` app (per screenshot above)

Answer (score 2):

Zune isn't supported in Windows Phone 8, have to use something else to synch music:

http://www.techhive.com/article/2023576/how-to-sync-media-to-windows-phone-8.html

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/music/sync-music-ringtones-and-podcasts-using-my-computer

Answer (score 1):

There is no support of Zune for Windows Phone 8. You have to do it manually or use the Windows 8 app ([here](https://www.windowsphone.com/fr-FR/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop)) to do it. Media player works too.